# Finding minimizers numerically in Matlab with 'fsolve'

Tags: matlab, minimize, nonlinear-optimization

I'm completely new to Matlab and I've been having some problems with my code.

I need to use 'fsolve' to locate minimizers to a nonlinear optimization problem, but I can't get it to work.
I've been using the 'Solution Process of Nonlinear System' part from [mathworks](https://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html).

My code is the following:

```
function F = myfun(x)
F = [4*x(4) + 2*x(1) - x(3)*(2*x(1) + 4) + 4*x(1)*(x(1).^2 + x(2) - 11) + 2*x(2).^2 - 14; 
x(3) - 10*x(4) + 2*x(2) + 4*x(2)*(x(2).^2 + x(1) - 7) + 2*x(1).^2 - 22; 
x(2) - (x(1) + 2).^2; 
4*x(1) - 10*x(2);];
x0 = [-5;-5];
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');
[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun,x0,options);
end
```

Where it says that; the value assigned to x appears to be unused as well as; not enough input arguments. But accoring to the mathworks page, I've done the exact same thing as them, so I'm sort of lost now.

Comment: The function `F = myfun(x)` should only contain the `F = [...]` part.  It is a function that takes a vector `x` and returns the value of your cost function. The last three lines define an intial point x0 and some options before calling fsolve. This should happen outside the function. Otherwise the function would be calling itself. Make a script that contains the last three lines and see what that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you are not doing correctly:

1. The function `myfun` must only contain equations (as mentioned in Florian's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186806/finding-minimizers-numerically-in-matlab-with-fsolve/42188512#comment71538299_42186806)).
2. `fsolve`, `x0` and `options` must be called from a separate script or from the Command Window.
3. The initial point array `x0` must have at least as many elements as variables (`x(4)`, `x(3)`, `x(2)`, `x(1)`) present in the equations in `myfun`.

---

Edit your function `myfun`, make sure that it only contains equations and save it in your working directory.

```
function F = myfun(x)
F = [4*x(4) + 2*x(1) - x(3)*(2*x(1) + 4) + 4*x(1)*(x(1)^2 + x(2) - 11) + 2*x(2)^2 - 14;
    x(3) - 10*x(4) + 2*x(2) + 4*x(2)*(x(2)^2 + x(1) - 7) + 2*x(1)^2 - 22;
    x(2) - (x(1) + 2)^2;
    4*x(1) - 10*x(2)];
end
```

Note that you don't need to use the element-wise power operator `.^`. Using the `^` operator will be enough to define powers in your equations.

Now in the Command Window enter the following instructions:

```
x0 = [-5;-5;-5;-5];
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');
[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun,x0,options);
```

Note that I modified `x0` to have at least 4 elements in order to match the number of equations that you defined in `myfun`. These are just sample values, so you should modify `x0` with the values of your problem.

This is a fragment of the output:

```
                                         Norm of      First-order   Trust-region
 Iteration  Func-count     f(x)          step         optimality    radius
     0          5           81521                      4.27e+04               1
     1         10         12608.5              1       1.15e+04               1
     2         15         966.243            2.5       1.71e+03             2.5
     3         20         408.322           6.25            685            6.25
     4         21         408.322         15.625            685            15.6
     5         26         263.815        3.90625            244            3.91
     6         27         263.815        9.76563            244            9.77
     7         32          205.88        2.44141            272            2.44
     8         37          138.11        6.10352            206             6.1
     9         42         93.4561        6.10352            105             6.1
    10         47         64.0129        6.10352           42.3             6.1
    ...
```